# How to prove that the barycentric subdivision of a simplicial complex can be obtained as a sequence of stellar subdivisions

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I have been reading about the topological invariance of simplicial homology groups, and at one point a weaker result is needed, namely the invariance of homology groups under barycentric subdivision. I've been reading both Armstrong's *"Basic Topology"* and Giblins's *"Graphs, Surfaces and Homology"* and both take the same approach to prove this fact: they obtain the barycentric subdivision of a complex by repeated application of a simpler operation called stellar subdivision. The required definitions are as follows:

- The **barycentre** of an $n$-simplex $\sigma=(v_0,...,v_n)$ is the point $\widehat{\sigma}=\frac{1}{n+1}(v_0+\dots+v_n)\in\sigma$.
- Given a simplicial complex $K$, the **cone** of a subcomplex $L$ with vertex $v\notin |L|$ is the complex comprised of $v$, the simplexes of $L$, and the simplexes created by adding to each of the latter the vertex $v$.
- The **first barycentric subdivision** of $K$, denoted $\boldsymbol{K^1}$, is the simplicial complex created by replacing, in order of increasing dimension, each simplex $\sigma\in K$ by the cone of its boundary with vertex its barycentre $\hat{\sigma}$.
- The simplical complex $K'$ obtained from $K$ by **stellar subdivision** of $\sigma$ is the one in which the simplexes of $K$ which do not have $\sigma$ as a face are left untouched, while for each $\sigma'\in K$ with $\sigma$ as a face, we consider $L$ the subcomplex of the boundary of $\sigma'$ comprised of the simplexes which do not have $\sigma$ as a face, and replace $\sigma'$ by the cone of $L$ with vertex $\hat{\sigma}$.

Then it is stated that the barycentric  subdivision of $K$ can be obtained by stellar-subdividing each of its simplexes in order of decreasing dimension. Both books give a visual example to convince the reader this statement is true, but neither of them gives a formal proof of the fact.

At first, I did not know why all of this was even necessary, since we already had a method of obtaining the barycentric subdivision of $K$ by repeated application of a simple operation as explained in the definition, but then I realized that after applying the operation described to a single simplex, the result is *not* necessarily a simplicial complex.

So now, I'd like to formally prove that the method described using stellar subdivisions does indeed yield the desired barycentric subdivision. I'm at a loss at how to do that, though, since I don't know how I can prove two simplicial complexes obtained by so different methods are the same.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Hint: We have the lemma: If $K,L$ are two simplicial complexes such that $K\subseteq L$ and $|K|=|L|$, then $K=L$. Now we can show that each simplex $[\hat{A_0},\hat{A_1},\dots,\hat{A_k}]$ of the barycentric subdivision appears after repeated stellar division. The idea is $[\hat{A_0},v_{i_1},v_{i_2},\dots,v_{i_k}]$ appears some stellar subdivisions and then $[\hat{A_0}, \hat{A_1},v_{j_1},v_{j_2},\dots,v_{j_r}]$ appears after a few more stellar subdivisions and so on...